# How to use .NET webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services, exception, soap

When I am sending request in server. It throws an exception like:

```
"SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. 
---> There is no row at position 0.' faultactor: 'null' 
detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@40776970".
```

Is this exception from Android side or WebService side?

Anyone please help me..

Comment: More information please... What webservice are you trying to call? How  does your request look like? How does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your request. Check your soap request. It seems that some value in request parameter is `null`.